# Subtract two QDateTime

Tags: python, pyqt5, mysql-python, qdatetime

My problem is trying to find the time difference between two different QDateTime. I can not find a function that subtracts QDateTime. Would I have to make it to a string and create a function that subtracts or make it to a list and create a function that subtracts. I also want to storage both times and the difference in a MySql database.

I know how to add and subtract seconds, days, months, and years for one QDateTime by using addSecs, addDays, etc.

Here is an example:

PyQt5.QtCore.QDateTime(2000, 1, 31, 23, 0)

PyQt5.QtCore.QDateTime(2000, 2, 1, 0, 0)

Mon Jan 31 23:00:00 2000

Tue Feb 1 00:00:00 2000

['Mon', 'Jan', '31', '23:00:00', '2000']

['Tue', 'Feb', '1', '00:00:00', '2000']

Here the code:

```
    def enter(self):
        self.a= self.dateTimeEdit.dateTime()
        self.b= self.dateTimeEdit_2.dateTime()
        print(self.a)
        print(self.b)
        print(self.a.toString())
        print(self.b.toString())
        print(self.a.toString().split())
        print(self.b.toString().split())
```

The difference should be an hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`secsTo`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#secsTo) method of `QDateTime`:

> Returns the number of seconds from this datetime to the *other* datetime. If the other datetime is earlier than this datetime, the value returned is negative.

`self.a.secsTo(self.b)` corresponds to subtracting `self.a` from `self.b` and should return `3600`.

Alternatively, `QDateTime` also has the [`msecsTo`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#msecsTo) and [`daysTo`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#daysTo) methods for respectively the difference in milliseconds and in days, which you use in the same way.